# How can I link a Xcode Storyboard Table cells to other storyboards?

Tags: uitableview, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I've run into a problem where I have roughly 200 "scenes/controllers in one storyboard. This causes massive delay and eats up my Memory in Xcode. So my thought is, since all of these link to one UITableView. Why not be able to split up the scenes/controllers into separate storyboards and link them accordingly.

The problem now is I have static cells I've created in storyboard mode. So there are 30 Rows inside of this UITable.

How can I call each row out of the 30, and have them link to a separate storyboard???
My initial thought was to give each cell a reuseidentifier. But even with that, I'm at a loss.

Please can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.
In case anyone else runs into this issue here's the solution..

Make sure to add on your main controller all the .h files
For me they would be

```
#import "tabbar26.h"
```

Now here is the code that I added to make it work

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
     cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [super tableView:tableView
                   cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];


            if (row == 1)
        {
            NSLog(@"hi");

        }

        if (row == 27)
        {
        }
 }

return cell;
}
```

This part above, really is not needed. I was just using it for Logging.

BELOW is what you need really :)

```
 -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath      {

NSUInteger row = [indexPath row];

if (row == 0)
{
    NSLog(@"hi2");
    }

if (row == 25)
{
    NSLog(@"bye2");
    UIStoryboard *tabbar26 = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"tabbar26" bundle:nil];
       UIViewController *Tab1_ViewController = [tabbar26 instantiateInitialViewController];
     [self.navigationController pushViewController:Tab1_ViewController animated:(YES)];
}

[self.tableView reloadData];
}
```